# Is there any solution for the {"detail":"Method \"POST\" not allowed."}

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, view, postman

views.py code:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAdminUser])
def createProduct(request):

    user = request.user
    product = Product.objects.create(
        user = user,
        name = 'sample name',
        price =4,
        countInStock = 12,
        category = 'Sample category',
        brand = 'Sample Brand',
        description = 'Sample Description',

    )

    serializer = ProductSerializer(product, many=False)
    return Response( serializer.data )
```

urls.py

```
path('products/create/',views.createProduct , name='product-create'),
```

Error that i got :

```
{"detail":"Method \"POST\" not allowed."}
```

Comment: Try to do it without decorator.

Comment: Try to apply such behaviour using class based view and routers for the url.